# how to limit number of concurrent users

Tags: spring, rest, timeout

i work on a spring 4 web app rest with angularjs
i have to limit the number of users connected at the same time because sometimes it's very slow and users have timeout. The goal is to show a modal with a message when the max users is reached
it would be a first step before a better monitoring

Comment: well what i can suggest is to put an interceptor who counts the active users and store them in a shared bean. Then you can check this bean to see if the max limit is reached

Comment: Is your backend app stateless or stateful?

Comment: stateful, i thought i could make it with spring security